# How to write a custom @Html.ControlFor(o => o.Property)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

I want to create a custom method, to be able to call it as

```
@Html.PaginationFor(o => o.List)
```

I started looking at reflector, but I don't know exactly what it is doing over there. I tried:

```
public static MvcHtmlString PaginationFor<TModel, TProperty>(this Html<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    var propertyValue = ????????
    return html.Partial("View", propertyValue);
}
```

How do I extract the property value from the expression to pass as a model of the partial view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static MvcHtmlString PaginationFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression
)
{
    TModel model = html.ViewData.Model;
    var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
    var propertyValue = metaData.Model; // This will be of type TProperty
    return html.Partial("View", propertyValue);
}
```

Comment: This won't work, he wants the property value from the Model and not the model itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static MvcHtmlString PaginationFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression) {

    var func = expression.Compile();

    var propertyValue = func(html.ViewData.Model);
    return html.Partial("View", propertyValue);
}
```